# Ошибка при выполнении кода Python на PythonAnyWhere

Tags: telegram-bot, консоль, pythonanywhere

Запускаю код telegram бота из Bash console. Спустя какое-то время (7-45 мин) появляется ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как-то избежать её появления или сделать так, чтобы сразу после её появления автоматически выполнялась определённая команда?

Текст ошибки:

```
2018-05-07 17:42:57,167 (util.py:65 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ReadTimeout occurred, args=(ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool
(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=30)",),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/UserName/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/home/UserName/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1002, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 865, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 625, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
```

Comment: Ошибку текстом приведите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Добавил к вопросу